# wmic output difference in cmd and batch ..why?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

here is the issue i dont understand

I'm executing the following command in cmd (win7):

```
>wmic netuse where "LocalName="Z:"" get UserName /value
```

The output is wonderful as follows:

```
UserName=ASI\kote
```

(there are 2-3 blank lines in top and bottom of this command output which cant be shown in typed format here)

Now, I want to run this command in a batch script and get its output. So here is my simple batch code for the same:

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=," %%a in ("X:,Y:,Z:") do (
    echo %%a,%%b,%%c
    set currDrive=%%c
    echo wmic netuse where "LocalName="!currDrive!"" get UserName /value
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=*" %%a in ('wmic netuse where "LocalName="!currDrive!"" get UserName ^/value') do (
        echo %%a,%%b,"%%c"
        if "%%a"=="UserName" (
            set mappedDriveUser=%%c
            echo ===="mappedDriveUser!"
            echo org"%%c"
            rem set mappedDriveUser=!mappedDriveUser:^ =!
            rem echo ====!mappedDriveUser!
            rem echo Drive !currDrive! is connected through user !mappedDriveUser!
        ) else (
            rem donothing
        )
    )
)
echo end
```

Here is the batch output I get:

```
X:,Y:,Z:
wmic netuse where "LocalName="Z:"" get UserName /value
,,""
,,""
,,""Name=ASI\kote
,,""
,,""
,,""
end
```

The batch output changes-User is gone and actual var is coming out of "" . I believe it should come inside  the double quotes
I need to understand the same.
Also, I need tips to get the 'correct' wmic cmd output in batch script - which is what i get when I run the command in cmd terminal.
Thnks in advance

Comment: PS: These drives are mapped drives of some remote location on my PC

Comment: I prefer to use this type of structure `In ('"WMIC NetUse Where (LocalName='!currDrive!') Get UserName /Value"') Do`.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the `wmic` command, with `get`'s `/value` switch is something like (with additional empty lines)

```
 UserName=Where\Who
```

If we use the `for /f` options to tokenize the string using the `=` as delimiter to separate the field name (token 1) from its value (token 2) and only process the lines with data in the second token, then we can write something like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%d in (f: g: h:) do (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('
            wmic netuse where "localname='%%d'" get username ^/value
        ') do if not "%%b"=="" (
            echo Drive %%d mapped through %%b
        )
    )
```

There is not any *need* to store the values inside the `for` replaceable parameters into variables if you don't use them later, directly use the replaceable parameter

**note**: values retrieved from the `wmic` output usually contain an ending carriage return. An additional `for` command may be required to discard it if necessary.

This code (almost the same, just `[]` added)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%d in (f: g: h:) do (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('
            wmic netuse where "localname='%%d'" get username ^/value
        ') do if not "%%b"=="" (
            echo Drive %%d mapped through [%%b]
        )
    )
```

will generate, showing the additional carriage return

```
]rive f: mapped through [.CN=myUserName.OU=X01.O=X
]rive g: mapped through [.CN=myUserName.OU=X01.O=X
]rive h: mapped through [.CN=myUserName.OU=X01.O=X
```

This can be handled with something like (see the additional `for` loop)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%d in (f: g: h:) do (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('
            wmic netuse where "localname='%%d'" get username ^/value
        ') do if not "%%b"=="" for /f "delims=" %%c in ("%%b") do (
            echo Drive %%d mapped through [%%c]
        )
    )
```

generating

```
Drive f: mapped through [.CN=myUserName.OU=X01.O=X]
Drive g: mapped through [.CN=myUserName.OU=X01.O=X]
Drive h: mapped through [.CN=myUserName.OU=X01.O=X]
```

Comment: I looked into the carriage return problem with a debugger. It turns out wmic is erroneously printing lines that already have CRLF line endings to a C text-mode stream, which converts LF to CRLF. This results in strings that end with CRCRLF. Stripping off the trailing CRLF -- as a `for /f` loop does -- still leaves a trailing carriage return.

Comment: @eryksun, thank you, answer updated. As you can see, the `for /f` can remove the CR.

Comment: Of course. Maybe one day Microsoft will fix this bug in wmic. It should print strings with LF line endings, and leave the translation to CRLF up to the stdio stream.

Comment: @eryksun, Just my opinion, I think nothing should be translated, what the code sends is what shoud be placed in the stream, period. Another question is how this stream should be handled/shown by a console/terminal, but the data itself should not be changed.

Comment: The C runtime on Windows has always translated the standard C/Unix LF line ending to CRLF. It also handles Ctrl+Z (0x1A) as EOF when reading in text mode, which you may be used to using with `copy con ...`. Text mode I/O is just in the C runtime. WinAPI file I/O is binary (e.g. `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`). The rules for C text mode in Windows are inherited from DOS, which inherited them from CP/M.

Comment: @eryksun, I know it, thank you. But knowing it (and being aware of all the problems that changing it could generate), doesn't mean I like it.

Comment: Even in Python 3, the high-level `TextIOWrapper` for text mode defaults to translating LF to CRLF on Windows. You can configure this when opening a file, but generally scripts just use the platform default. One reason is that notepad is still the default association for text files on Windows, and it requires CRLF endings.